# running into migration conflicts with south

Tags: python, django, django-south

I am working with some other developers on a website (using Django) and as it is a new site and the database schema is constantly changing. We are using South for schema migration but are running into the issue where each of us have our own branch checked out and are working on our own separate part of the project. When the code is merged back in very often there have been multiple migrations generated for the same model (there might be three migrations with id 003 for model A).

It seems like South is pretty good about managing conflicts when they relate to different models:
http://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part5.html#team-workflow

But when dealing with the same model it gets a little messy manually creating the merged migration.

I was wondering if there was any better way of doing this or a better tool than South.

One idea I have is for no one to check in the migration files and just check in the model changes directly to git. That way every person would just run their own migrations and won't have to worry about conflicts. Not sure if that is a good practice...

I am curious how other people are managing these situations.

Thanks:)

Answer (score 2):

From the South documentation:

> Make sure your team know who is working on what, so they don’t write migrations that affect the same parts of the DB at the same time.

So that's the thing you shouldn't do: don't create migrations that affect the same model unless you're sure you're able to merge them later into the main development trunk. A tool can't figure out what the right database schema needs to be when two developers modify the same field of a model.

In that case you'll need to manually fix migrations and get the model fields in order. This could mean migrating back and constructing a new migration before merging the branch with the trunk.

Comment: So I guess the answer to problem x is "don't have problem x"?  How do you "manually fix migrations"?  How do you "construct a new migration" that doesn't just cause the same problem?

Comment: @EdwardNewell you need to decide what the correct field type is and then generate a migration that accomplishes that change. So it may mean discarding one of the migrations or throwing both away and creating a new one.